# Excel VBA Advanced Filter issue due to blank hyperlink criteria

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I'm having a bit of a nightmare trying to set up a VBA code in Excel. I'm successfully able to filter out data based using 1 column on a criteria range that is a list of peoples names, provided I only select the criteria range to the bottom of the list of the names (for example $AM$2001:$AM$2100).

The issue is I want to go beyond that bottom of the list of names into the blank cells so that if I add any names in future it will automatically update accordingly. However, because the list is hyperlinked from a separate sheet, the criteria is picking up the 0's and showing all the blanks in the filter result.

How to adjust my code so that these "blank" cells or "0" cells don't show up? Will it just not work because of the hyperlink? My current code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("$F$1:$F$2000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range _ 
       ("$AM$2001:$AM$2200"), Unique:=False  
End Sub
```

As said, the issue seems to be because the list of names actually ends at AM2100, not AM2200. AM2101 to AM2200 are all filled with 0 from the hyperlinked sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("$F$1:$F$2000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range _ 
       ("$AM$2001:$AM$" & UsedRange.Rows.Count()), Unique:=False  
End Sub
```

if that still brings in too many cells (used range bigger than number of used rows in column AM try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("$F$1:$F$2000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range _ 
       ("$AM$2001:$AM$" & Range("$AM$2001").End(xlDown).Row()), Unique:=False  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried your one there and it takes it back to not working at all. With my one I get down to the correct list of names but also all the blanks, but with yours I get everything and the blanks, almost as if it hasn't filtered at all.

Comment: Apologies it should have said    ("$AM$2001:$AM$" & UsedRange.Rows.Count()). I started and ended the range on the same cell

Comment: Also I should add that because the blank cells in the criteria are hyperlinked they aren't really "blank". Only the source of the hyperlink is blank. The cell actually reads ='Name List'!C19 and then 20, 21, 22 etc.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I've given both a go but in both instances I still end up in the same position where all the empties or "0" don't filter out.

Comment: I've tried to come up with some solutions, there are ways to use And, OR and various other things like does not equal but without seeing the data it's hard to know what's going on. Very sorry